# Union of two automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I need to find a minimal DFA given the following information:

> $ \{a^nb : n\geq 0\} \cup \{b^na: n \geq 1\}$

Now, maybe I'm not seeing this properly, but I don't see how this is possible: the first one will take 0 or more a's followed by one b, whereas the second one will take a 1 or more b's followed by one a.

Drawing the combined automata only brought me to trap states. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just try to build _one_ automaton for both. It isn't even hard to do.

Comment: Constructing an *N*FA for the union is trivial, determinising and minimising is easy, if not trivial, with the algorithms you know from lecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@vonbrand](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/6447/vonbrand) suggested, using one automata (without attempting to combine them) is sufficient. Combining them will prove to be more work than it's worth.

Basically, here's the idea:

- If you get an $a$, begin looping on $a^nb$. If you get a $b$ after this, accept. But anything further goes to the trash can.
- If you get a $b$, accept for $a^0b$. If you get another $b$, you can then loop on $b$ under $b^na$. At any point in the loop, if you get an $a$, accept. But if you get anything after that $a$, go to the trash can.

Here is a textual representation (`t` is the "trash can" or trap state; `+` represents an accept state).

```
  | 0   | 1   | 2+  | 3+  | 4+  | 5
a | 1   | 1   | 4   | t   | t   | 4
b | 2   | 3   | 5   | t   | t   | 5
```

And here is a generated visual version:

[image]

(*I'm not 100% sure this is minimal, but if it's not, it's a good exercise.*)

Comment: That's great! Thank you. Also, what program did you use to make that automaton? It would be great for submitting my work?

Comment: @jsan I found [a website called HackingOff](http://hackingoff.com/compilers) that has some visual representation generators. They're in SVG, though, so you may have to use a screenshot or something like PhotoShop to get the image to a usable format.

Comment: Also, could we not eliminate state 5, loop b on state 2. I believe this would make it minimal.

Comment: @jsan I'm afraid not. If we loop on state 2, the automaton will accept `bb` since state 2 is an accept state.

Comment: @jsan use graphviz, it's great for rendering graphs and automata in particular. It's easy to learn.

Comment: It isn't minimal. You can e.g. identify 3 and 4 ;)

Comment: @vonbrand Ah, good point. That's actually a pretty obvious change, I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: In some texts determinic automata are required to have a (unique) transition for every letter at every state. Here that means adding a "garbage" state and edges to that state from 3 (and 4).

Comment: @HendrikJan Yeah, I mentioned that in the table representation. I tend to refrain from adding them in visual representations as they often end up with very, very long, cluttered arrows.

Comment: @Eric Sorry I missed that in the table. I wanted to make it explicit as the question seems by a beginner.

Comment: @jsan Another great tool for generating an automaton is [http://madebyevan.com/fsm/](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/).